# Split long string to obtain multiple values/strings - google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have complex string in which I need to pull single words and/or multiple words.

Here is the string:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="5" yahoo:created="2013-07-28T18:37:23Z" yahoo:lang="en-US"><diagnostics><publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable><user-time>145</user-time><service-time>141</service-time><build-version>38483</build-version></diagnostics><results><Result xmlns="urn:yahoo:cate">**RED**</Result><Result xmlns="urn:yahoo:cate">**GREEN**</Result><Result xmlns="urn:yahoo:cate">**BLUE**</Result><Result xmlns="urn:yahoo:cate">**A, E, I, O, U **</Result><Result xmlns="urn:yahoo:cate">**SOMETIMES Y**</Result></results></query><!-- total: 145 -->
```

(I really wish that wouldn't scroll, since it makes it difficult to see the entire picture)

Anyway, I need to be able to pull out the:

RED

GREEN

BLUE

A, E, I, O, U

SOMETIMES Y

++++ btw, I tried to make those values BOLD in the big string, but they show up with asteriks instead. Disredard the asterisks. They are not part of the string. However I'm leaving them in there since it makes them easier to find when you look at the entire string)
++++

My goal is to turn that complex string into this:

RED|GREEN|BLUE|A, E, I, O, U|SOMETIMES Y

My preference is to do this on the sheet level using a single nested function (or a combination of multiple functions if necessary).

Failing that, a script version would be preferable to nothing.

I've been at this for ***hours*** using SPLIT, FIND, SUBSTITUTE, and a few other things that I tried on a whim - just to try *everything*. But I've now reached the saturation point of thinking clearly on this, and I'm hoping that someone can put me on a path for how to attack this logically.

I'm truly stumped (and frustrated).

==========================================

I said that I'd post the solution if I figured out the sheet-level solution, so this is it:

```
=mid(substitute(substitute(regexreplace(mid(A1,find("<Result",A1),find("</query",A1)-find("<Result",A1)),"<.*?>+","-"),"--","|"),"-","|"),2,len(substitute(substitute(regexreplace(mid(A1,find("<Result",A1),find("</query",A1)-find("<Result",A1)),"<.*?>+","-"),"--","|"),"-","|"))-2)
```

Comment: I should add that this example returns 5 keyword(s). However there can be any number of keyword(s) that will be within the string, including zero keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using XmlService Services? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service

Simple example:

```
    /* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
    function testXML() {
      var result = [];
      var document = XmlService.parse('<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="5" yahoo:created="2013-07-28T18:37:23Z" yahoo:lang="en-US"><diagnostics><publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable><user-time>145</user-time><service-time>141</service-time><build-version>38483</build-version></diagnostics><results><Result xmlns="urn:yahoo:cate">RED</Result><Result xmlns="urn:yahoo:cate">GREEN</Result><Result xmlns="urn:yahoo:cate">BLUE</Result><Result xmlns="urn:yahoo:cate">A, E, I, O, U</Result><Result xmlns="urn:yahoo:cate">SOMETIMES Y</Result></results></query><!-- total: 145 -->');
      var entries = document.getRootElement().getChildren('results')[0].getChildren();
      for (var i = 0, len = entries.length; i < len; ++i)
        result.push(entries[i].getText());
      Logger.log(result.join('|'));
    }
```

Comment: I had NOT considered that.... because it is beyond my familiarity with javascript to even _think_ of such a solution. But it certainly works! (you are a GENIOUS!). Btw, I've never asked this question before because I feel foolish for not knowing the answer, but if I finally ask now, then I won't have to feel foolish anymore, and i'll have actually learned something new and useful. So here goes: How do I turn the "logger" result into CELL results on the page?

Comment: On another note, I have come up with a sheet level solution using LEN, FIND, RIGHT, REGEXREPLACE, and SPLIT (in separate cells - so far) to accomplish this. Now I just need to figure out how to nest it all, and include a CONCATENATE into the mix as well. I'll post the sloution if I can figure out how to nest it all properly.

Comment: to write in a serie of cells use this : `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,1,result.length).setValues([result]);` for a single row. if you need it in columns let us know

Comment: Ok, that wasn't something that I would have come up with on my own, so I'm actually glad that I asked. Thank you! Btw, William added a join to his solution, so now I'm trying to include that as part of the result. It's obviously not as simple as adding `.join('|')` to `result`, as I encounter errors. I'm skunked.

Comment: He added `join('|')` only to get a readable result with `|` separators, you shouldn't use it when writing back to a spreadsheet. What you need is a matrix (a 2 dimension array) to be able to `setValues` in the SS. Maybe you should start a new post on how to write array data to SS ?